# How can I scale element height and width using CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a way using CSS to scale elements. For example, if I have an image, how can I say

```
img.height = image.height * 0.75  // scale down to 0.75
```

using CSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
div.zoomed { zoom: 0.75; -moz-transform: scale(0.75); }
```

Should work in: Firefox 3.5, IE 5.5+, Opera, Safari 4, Chrome

**Edit:**
You should also add `-webkit-transform: scale(0.75);` for Chrome and Safari, although latest versions supports `zoom`

Comment: what is the 'zoom:0.75' for if  '-moz-transform: scale(0.75)' works?

Comment: "zoom" is for IE, Chrome... "-moz-transform" is only for Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

As of CSS 2.1 you cannot change dimensions of one element depending on other element (including itself) dimensions.

You will have to use JavaScript for this.

It probably will be possible in CSS3 with  CSS variables.